# jquery themes not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-theme

Any idea why jquery ui theme is not working in jsfiddle, but it works on my localhost?

http://jsfiddle.net/oshirowanen/UxvaG/

Comment: there's error showing in you code

Comment: u need to include all necessary CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JS expects a portlet class, while the HTML uses the widget class.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `$(document).load` wrapper or chage to **nowrap** from drop down at left. http://jsfiddle.net/UxvaG/1/

```
        $( ".column" ).sortable({
            connectWith: ".column"
        });

        $( ".portlet" ).addClass( "ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all" )
            .find( ".portlet-header" )
                .addClass( "ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" )
                .prepend( "<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick'></span>")
                .end()
            .find( ".portlet-content" );

        $( ".portlet-header .ui-icon" ).click(function() {
            $( this ).toggleClass( "ui-icon-minusthick" ).toggleClass( "ui-icon-plusthick" );
            $( this ).parents( ".portlet:first" ).find( ".portlet-content" ).toggle();
        });

        $( ".column" ).disableSelection();
```

If you select `onLoad` on the left corner where you select lib, then jsfiddle will automatically wrap the code inside `$(document).load({})`

Answer (score 0):

u must missing some CSS, use ThemeROller

> Download a ThemeRoller theme: The
>   easiest way to build a theme is to use
>   the ThemeRoller to generate and
>   download a theme. This app will create
>   a new ui.theme.css file and and images
>   directory containing all necessary
>   background images and icon sprites
>   which can simply be dropped into your
>   project. This approach will be the
>   easiest to create and maintain but
>   limits customization to the options
>   provided in ThemeRoller

[reference](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming)